# Trigger multiple actions from a single request in Struts

Tags: struts

I'm new with structs, so pardon if I'm not using the correct terms or being too vague.

I have multiple forms on a page. I have each form's action property tied to separate actions in struts-config. Each form's submission works correctly. But I'd also like to prepopulate all of the forms when the page loads.

I tried creating multiple s in struts config, all with the same path but each with different type properties. But only the final  seems to be executed. Is there a way I can make all of these actions execute, or is there some way to make an action trigger other actions, or something like that? I would just make one setup controller, but you can only tie a single form to an action, so I don't think that would work.

I think I'm using Struts 1.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It'd probably be a good idea to figure out which version you're using, too, as they are completely different frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your form data is related, but even if its not, but one strategy that can work is implementing a base data, eg:

```
public class DataAction extends ActionSupport
{
   private Data1 data1 = new Data1() // or whatever strategy of populating data
   public Data1 getData() { return data1 }
   public void execute()
   {
      // any common execution code
   }
 }
```

and then extend the action for each form

```
public class Form1Action extends DataAction
{
  public void execute()
  {
     super.execute();
     // unique execution code
  }
}
```

then from your jsp page, just call the data object(s) for each form, as they will be inherited form the base class.  For situations where you don't want to load a data object on each request of the Action, you can simply use some logic in the base Data class and have the extending class use that logic to decide whether or not to prepopulate that data object.

Another strategy, is to have an individual Action process all your forms. Again this only makes sense depending on your data and your design. If they aren't logically related, don't merge them into a single action.

Comment: Also the better question that Dave asked above is why do you want to do this. I can imagine a few use cases, but they might not be your case.  Depending on your design and data, even the Struts2 solution I proposed above could be totally inappropriate.